# How to import a local package into a Vite project?

Tags: vite, tsconfig, tsc, tsconfig.json

As `react-scripts` is not maintained since 2 years and still use TypeScript v4, I would like to change my stack.

After a few researches, I decided to try Vite.js.

I import my local library like this in my package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "my-local-lib": "file:../my-local-lib",
    ...
```

My problem is when I import something from it

> import { CONTACT_EMAIL } from 'my-local-lib/dist/constants';

I get the following error in my browser console:

> hmr.ts:247 SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/my-local-lib/dist/constants.js' does not provide an export named 'CONTACT_EMAIL' (at App.jsx:6:10)

So Vite is expecting to read the source file `/my-local-lib/src/constant.js`

```js
export const CONTACT_EMAIL = 'example@example.com';
```

When it's actually reading my compiled file `/my-local-lib/dist/constant.js`:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.CONTACT_EMAIL = 'contact@handballdashboard.com';
//# sourceMappingURL=constants.js.map
```

Steps to reproduce:

- `pnpm create vite my-react-app --template react`
- `cd my-react-app`
- `pnpm add ../my-local-lib`
- `pnpm install`

I'm building my local library with `tsc` and the following TypeScript options:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "es2019" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
        "jsx": "react-jsx" /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */,

        /* Modules */
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
        "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
        "sourceMap": true, /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
        
        /* Emit */
        "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
        "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    
        /* Interop Constraints */
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

        /* Completeness */
        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    }
}
```